# How can I disable scroll in GridView?

Tags: flutter

I have a GridView whose parent is `ListView`. How can I disable scroll in `GridView` so users can scroll the ListView?
I can't find any attribute in GridView to disable scroll even the content is fully rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can disable it by setting primary property as below:

```
GridView.count(
     shrinkWrap: true,
     primary: true,
     children: <Widget>[],
     // ...
)
```

Or if you want to disable it entirely:

```
hysics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

Comment: `physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` solves my problem

Comment: `primary: false,` for me